# WPF: parsing geometries ignores language

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I embed a ResourceDictionary inside a resource file in my project.  This dictionary contains a bunch of geometries.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Geometry x:Key="pin">M20.5,15L11.5,15C10.396,15 9.5,15.896 9.5,17 9.5,18.104 10.396,19 11.5,19L20.5,19C21.604,19 22.5,18.104 22.5,17 22.5,15.896 21.604,15 20.5,15z M13.583,8L12.5,14 19.5,14 18.416,8 13.583,8z M16,29L17.5,20 14.5,20 16,29z M13,7L19,7C19.828,7 20.5,6.328 20.5,5.5 20.5,4.672 19.828,4 19,4L13,4C12.171,4 11.5,4.672 11.5,5.5 11.5,6.328 12.171,7 13,7z</Geometry>
  <Geometry ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I'm able to load the dictionary without any problem using:

```
var rd = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;
```

When I inspect the values of the dictionary entries, I get different results whether my PC uses English or French culture.

When my PC uses English, the value is:

```
M20.5,15L11.5,15C10.396,15 9.5,1...
```

But if my PC uses French, the value is:

```
M20,5;15L11,5;15C10,396;15 9,5;1...
```

And then when I try to use Geometry.Parse, it asserts since the string is not using standard geometry nomenclature.

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary)
{
    var Data = Geometry.Parse(entry.Value.ToString());   <--- ASSERTS HERE
    ...
```

---

Instead of *Application.LoadComponent*, I tried using XamlReader to parse the embedded dictionary:

```
var info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
var context = new ParserContext() { XmlLang = "en-US" };
var reader = new XamlReader();
var rd = reader.LoadAsync(info.Stream, context) as ResourceDictionary;
```

I end up having the same results inside my dictionary entries.  The characters are still converted.  It's like the parsercontext is ignored.

---

I tried forcing the language at the root of the ResourceDictionary with **xml:lang="en-US"**, I tried forcing it inside the geometry items.  I am unable to receive the unaltered string.  Characters end up replaced.

---

Conclusion: the only hack I can do is replace the ';' with ',' and the ',' with '.' but this only works for French culture.  This is not the solution I am looking for.

Can anybody help me understand how to load my resource properly without being culture-bullied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `Geometry`; `Parse` and `ToString` should be symmetrical.

As a workaround, you can use the invariant culture when transforming the resource to a string:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary)
{
    string valueAsString = ((Geometry)entry.Value).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var Data = Geometry.Parse(valueAsString);
    ...
```

That being said, I'm not sure why you need to do `ToString` and `Parse`... can't you just cast the resource to `Geometry`?

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary)
{
    var Data = (Geometry)entry.Data;
    ...
```

I reported the issue [on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3132161), but I doubt it will ever be fixed...

Comment: You made my day.  I didn't know casting a string into a Geometry worked while preserving the current culture.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BriocheBro you can't cast a string to a `Geometry`, but the object in the resources is not a string, it's already an instance of `Geometry`.